# I am getting Expected identifier in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, identifier

I'm making an app for iPhone using obj-c that finds side lengths and angles for triangles. Part of the app uses the Pythagorean Theorem.

```
NSNumber *pySidea = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[sideA text] integerValue]];
NSNumber *pySideb = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[sideB text] integerValue]];
NSNumber *pySidec = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[sideC text] integerValue]];

int pyAside = [pySidea intValue];
int pyBside = [pySideb intValue];
int pyCside = [pySidec intValue];

if ([aSide length] = 0) {
    NSString *finalAnserc = [sqrtf(powf(pyAside, 2) + powf(pyBside, 2))];
    sideCstring = @"_anserSidec";
}
```

sideA, sideB and sideC are the sides of a triangle using a text field. I don't get an error for any part except

```
if ([aSide length] = 0) {
    NSString *finalAnserc = [sqrtf(powf(pyAside, 2) + powf(pyBside, 2))];
    sideCstring = @"_anserSidec";
}
```

where I get "Expected identifier". Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
NSString *finalAnserc = [sqrtf(powf(pyAside, 2) + powf(pyBside, 2))];
```

Seems to be wanting to create a string, but doesn't do anything except some arithmetic inside square brackets, which isn't valid syntax.  I think you want something like:

```
float answer = sqrtf(powf(pyAside, 2) + powf(pyBside, 2));
NSString *finalAnswer = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:answer] stringValue];
```

Calling `powf()` to square a number is a bit heavy-handed, too.  You could just write:

```
float answer = sqrtf(pyAside*pyAside + pyBside*pyBside);
```

As Nithin notes in his answer, you have a logical error with your `if` statement too - you want to be using `==` probably.

Comment: FYI there's also the standard function [`hypot(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hypot) to do the hypotenuse calculation, which also avoids overflow and underflow in the intermediate results (though that's not normally a concern).

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'if' condition , it should be `if([aSide length] == 0)`

Remember two equal (=) signs...

Comment: same problem. the error shows on the `NSString *finalAnserc = [sqrtf(powf(pyAside, 2) + powf(pyBside, 2))];` line

Comment: You're right that the comparison is wrong, but it's not the OP's specific problem.  He's getting a syntax error on his next line.  The `=` is syntactically correct, even though it's logically wrong.

Comment: The compiler should be flagging this as well...need to turn up the warning knob!

Comment: As far as I know, the length of a property is readonly and you can't assign value to it.

Comment: I have it set to comparing the length, but now I can't assign the string to the label.